# Friction when a cylinder rolls down an incline

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Let's say a cylinder of $M_T$ is rolling down an inclined plane of angle $\theta$. I want to determine the friction between the plane and the cylinder. Can I do this using only Euler-Lagrange? As in $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x}-\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{x}}=F_k$$

where $F_k$ is the friction, the only non-conservative force in this situation. No other force is transporting energy in our out of the system. My generalized coordinate is $x$, which is a horizontal line along the plane. This system has only one degree of freedom ; translational motion of the center of mass along this $x$ coordinate. I'm skeptical whether or not my friction $$F_k = M_t(g\sin\theta - \ddot{x})$$

is correct, since $F_k$ is now directly proportional to the incline ( It should not be ). Any suggestions?

Comment: you have 2 generalized coordinates the translation and the rotation of the zylinder

Comment: this ansatz $F_k = M_t(g\sin\theta - \ddot{x})$ is wrong, the friction force is depending on the normal force and the friction coefficient